# find f and $d_pf$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, stereographic-projections

Let $$S_1=\{(x,y,z) | x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}-\{N\}$$

$$S_2= \{(x,y,z,0) | x,y\in \Bbb R\}$$

$f:S_1\to S_2$

$f$ is stereographic projection.

,where $\ell$ is a line passing through 
$N=(0,0,1)$ and $p$

$f(p)= \ell \cap S_2=q$

[image]

I want to find $f$ and $d_pf$. Please help me to do this question. I googled and found many results but these are not understandable for me. I have seen such a projection at first time.

Comment: Look in [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection).

Comment: Looked in wiki. But I cannot understand from there. It seems so complicated to me as i said before. @user64494

Comment: To find $f$, you need only to use similar triangles.

Comment: How? I am new learner. So I am inexperienced. Please can you show explicitly? This is not Hw or else, just for an aim to learn Dear @John

Comment: Or, parametrize the line $NP$ as $N + t(N-p)$. Then find $t$ such that this lines hit the $(x, y, z, 0)$ plane (That is, set the fourth coordinate to be 0)

Comment: That's , i get $(x,y,z)=(\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2+1}, \frac{2y}{x^2+y^2+1}, \frac{-1+x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2+1})$. isnt it? @john

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S_2$ should be

$$S_2  = \{ (x, y, 0): x, y \in \mathbb R\} \subset \mathbb R^3$$

To write down $f:S_1 \to S_2$, Parametrize the line joining $N$ and $p = (x, y, z)$ by

$$N + t(N-p) = (0,0,1) + t (-x, -y, 1-z) = (-tx, -ty, 1+t(1-z))$$

$f(p)$ is the point where the $z$ coordinate is $0$, that is $t =1/(z-1)$.Thus

$$f(p) = \bigg(\frac{x}{1-z}, \frac{y}{1-z}, 0\bigg). $$

Comment: Then $$d_pf=\left [\begin{matrix} 1/(1-z) & 0 & -x(1-z)^{-2} \\ 0 &  1/(1-z) & -y(1-z)^{-2} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right ] . \left[\begin{matrix} x/(1-z) \\ y/(1-z) \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right ]$$

Comment: Is this also right?

Comment: Note that $df$ should be a $2\times 2$ matrix